# Flutter/Dart: How to get first name value from Firestore to be displayed on Home Screen after logging in to account?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the First Name of the user's account to be shown in the appbar of my Home Page. I have a class that determines if the current user is logged in or not upon starting the app, depending on if they are, it will show the login or home page. In this class is where I'm trying to do the logic to get the first name from the Firestore Database. I've tried expaining myself more in comments in the code. Here's my code so far:

```
class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  AuthPage({super.key});

  // will store the current user
  var user;
  // instance for the database
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<String> getFirstName(String uEmail) async {
    user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    var docSnapshot = await collection.doc(uEmail).get();
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;

      var name = data['First Name'];
      return name;
    }
    // have it returning the word "empty" just so I can know which return is being called  
    return "empty";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          // user has logged in
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // initially set to "test" just so I can see what happens to the field
            // This value that it's initally set to is what end ups being parsed through to the home page and shown in the app bar, not the actual name
            String firstName = "test";
            user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
            String userEmail = user!.email;
            getFirstName(userEmail).then((String result) {
              // this print was used to test if result is storing the correct value, which it does (ignore the 5, that just how I check things)
              print(result + " 5");
              // this is meant to then set the first name to result (the user's name) but it seems to not be working
              firstName = result;
            });
            // return the home page with the user's first name parsed so it can be used in the appbar
            return HomePage(firstName: firstName);
          }

          // user is NOT logged in
          else {
            return LoginOrRegisterPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: I was able to get this to work by doing the fetching from the Firestore and all of that in the Home Page, but I didn't like how there was a bit of a delay between the page showing on the device, and the name being shown on the screen (loading the name). Also, I may be wrong with this but since my home page is stateful and gets updated constantly, I think that would mean the logic for fetching and showing the name is redone everytime something changes (which is often in this project) and I didn't want that. I figured just fetching the name once in the Auth Page would be more efficient.

I'm expecting the First Name field stored in the Firestore to be fetched and parsed through to the Home Page, but whatever value my firstName variable is initially set to is getting parsed, not the fetched Name.

Comment: Wrap the HomePage(firstName: firstName) with a future builder; where getFirstName is the future;

Comment: https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-a-futurebuilder

Comment: @TheodoreMCA thank you so much, that worked perfectly!! you're a legend :)